# How to know if JBoss with preinstalled jboss MQ?

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss-messaging, jbossmq

I have already configured jboss 4.2.3, but i need to use jboss-mq. Looked at the deplot dir of my default server instance and i didn't find jms dir in it. How can i know if this jboss comes with jboss-mq, and where i can find all needed files for my server instance.
I know that hornetmq comes with some install script that will configure jboss to work with hornet, is there some scripr for jboss-mq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a jms directory in server/default/deploy that contains jms-ra.rar and assorted .xml files, and when you start the server you can see the JMS resource adapter deploying in the logs, e.g.

`INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)`

...logs snipped for brevity, then...

`INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar`

along with associated default JMS objects defined in jms-ds.xml, jbossmq-destinations-service.xml etc., for example

`INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'`

These files are present in the .zip I just unpacked to test, so if the directory is missing for you then there is something wrong with the install.